# Why doesn't EJBException use Throwable.cause?

Tags: java, ejb

Quite for a long time I'm wondering why doesn't *EJBException* use standard *Throwable.cause* field to reach an exception it wraps?

It complicates getting the original root cause to something like that

```
private String getRootCauseErrorMessage(final Exception ex) {
    Throwable currentException = ex;
    Throwable nextException = null;
    do {
        if (nextException != null) {
            currentException = nextException;
        }

        /* For some reason EJBException stores cause in a separate field rather the all generic Throwables */
        if (currentException instanceof EJBException) {
            nextException = ((EJBException) currentException).getCausedByException();
        } else {
            nextException = currentException.getCause();
        }
    } while (nextException != null);

    return currentException.getMessage();
}
```

ps: I'm on Java6 and EJB3

Comment: EJB is older than `Throwable.cause`, that's probably why.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's correct.  I've added an answer with a bit more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Throwable.getCause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) was not added until Java 1.4.  Some implementations of EJBException do retrofit the getCausedByException method to use the getCause method (similar to how the [RemoteException.getCause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/RemoteException.html#getCause--) method was retrofitted), but it sounds like your application server does not do this.

Comment: I see... Have never seen the retrofitted behavior before. Although have never worked close enough with other app servers than WebSphere and WebLogic )

Comment: @FlasHfromRu For WebSphere Application Server, we retrofitted EJBException.getCause in 8.0 so that getCause and getCausedByException are consistent.  There are some quirks because getCausedByException can only return Exception, so it's somewhat unclear what `((EJBException)new EJBException().initCause(new Error())).getCausedByException()` should return, but in general it works well.  The original motivation was to clean up redundant stack trace entries (printStackTrace elides redundant stack trace entries only for getCause).

Comment: That explains - we are still on WebSphere 7.
Anyway ultimate answer! Thanks!